# CSS3 Multiple backgrounds causing 404 in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

The following style causes a 404 to show up in our access logs:

```
background-image: url('/site/common/img/modal/headline.png'),
url('/site/common/img/modal/headline.png'),
url('/site/common/img/modal/headline.png');
```

I've tried it with and without quotes with the same result.

From access logs:

`...[11/Dec/2011:01:20:52 -0800] "GET /site/common/img/modal/headline.png),%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url(/site/common/img/modal/headline.png),%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url(/site/common/img/modal/headline.png HTTP/1.1" 404..`.

Apart from removing the styles for IE, is there a way to get IE to ignore these styles to avoid the 404?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a conditional stylesheet:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can include any HTML in between those comments, and it will be parsed only by IE.

Comment: I'd be curious to know, too. I had a recent multiple-backgrounds IE issue that was only solved with conditional stylesheet. If the downvoters are confident they know a better solution (and aren't just knee-jerking at conditional stylesheets) I'd love to see it.

Comment: I think it's downvoted because the main stylesheet will still be accessed regardless, so there'll still be a 404 :)